# Picker Animation Issue SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

I have a Picker that's just listing a bunch of strings, but when I switch from a longer string to a shorter string, it does this weird animation because it's confining the long string to the size of the short string then expanding it to the size of the long string. I can't post the video of it, but the picture shows the frame when going from "Club" to "Greek Life" where "Greek Life" is forced to three lines. It's a noticable hiccup when testing this on my phone and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

[image: Screenshot]

```swift
Section{
    Picker("List Type", selection: $selectedType) {
        Text("Standard").tag("Standard")
        Divider()
        Text("Class").tag("Class")
        Text("Club").tag("Club")
        Text("Greek Life").tag("Greek Life")
        Text("Sport").tag("Sport")
        Divider()
        Text("Work").tag("Work")
        Text("Personal").tag("Personal")
        Text("Groceries").tag("Groceries")
    }
}
```

Also, even if I explicitly set MenuStylePicker(), it does the same thing.

I've tried putting it in a frame, adding padding, etc. The only solution I found that worked was just using a Menu, but I'd prefer a Picker given that the clickable area is the entire section, as opposed to just the text.

Comment: Please see [ask] and include a [mre]

Comment: @jnpdx Fixed it

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on an iPhone 14 simulator running iOS 17.0. When an option is selected, the text changes instantaneously, even with animations slowed. Which iOS version are you testing with?

Comment: iOS17 with an iPhone 15 Pro. It does it on the simulator and on my iPhone when I test it. @BenzyNeez

Comment: I did another instance of a Picker in another view I’m working on, same situation different length strings and it did the same thing. Exact same setup as what I have here except the strings were different. @BenzyNeez

Comment: Also unable to reproduce the issue with iPhone 15 Pro, iOS17 (Simulator). Is it possible the problem is the (missing) surrounding code?